# @AppStorage uses "wrong" UserDefaults

Tags: swift, swiftui

I changed my code from UserDefaults to the new @AppStorage.

I read that without defining a suiteName für @AppStorage it will use UserDefaults.standard. In my case this does not seem to work:

I can get the Date from UserDefaults.standard with this `getLastContactDownload()` function:

```
struct Defaults {

private static let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard

static func getLastContactDownload() -> Date {
    return userDefault.object(forKey: "lastContactDownload") as? Date ?? Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -365 * 24 * 60 * 60)
}
}
```

And I save a value to it with `setLastContactDownload()` function:

```
static func setLastContactDownload(_ lastContactDownload: Date) {
    userDefault.set(lastContactDownload, forKey: "lastContactDownload")
}
```

In my View I use now the new @AppStorage:

```
@AppStorage("lastContactDownload") var lastContactDownload: Date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -365 * 24 * 60 * 60)
```

Now I would expect, that this gives me the same Dates:

```
.onAppear {
   print(lastContactDownload)
   print(Defaults.getLastContactDownload())
}
```

But it does not.

Console prints:

```
2020-02-18 10:21:22 +0000
2021-02-17 10:09:02 +0000
```

@AppStorage "lastContactDownload" seems to be nil and prints the default value which I defined (one year in the past).

Saving and reading the variable in the new @AppStorage way with `lastContactDownload = Date()` will work, but the point I am aiming at is, why does it not use the same UserDefaults.standard as the old way (I want to keep the values when changing my code to @AppStorage)?

Comment: Like you do for the UserDefaults variable, you need to save the new value to @AppStorage. When do you save this new value to @AppStorage? I can not see it in your code.

Comment: Saving and reading the variable in the new @AppStorage way with 'lastContactDownload = Date()' will work, but the point I am aiming at is, why does it not use the same UserDefaults.standard as the old way (I want to keep the values when changing my code to @AppStorage)?

Comment: I get your point. Probably AppStorage is acting like UserDefaults but on its own container. The best approach, in my opinion, would be to include a first version where AppStorage first value would be the one in UserDefaults. You will have your desired value in AppStorage this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found out now:

This seems to be a simulator bug. If I execute the same code on a real device I get the identical dates printed.